# Extreme memory consumption by geth

Tags: go-ethereum, json-rpc, memory

I'm using geth's traceTransaction() API to index certain opcodes that are used in transactions. When I request traces from some transactions (e.g. 0x36351fcbe7497e38f9036505498b0b76dd715294cc4b9aec1c4bc30a8193f05d) the memory usage becomes absolutely insane. I'm talking "crashing a 256 GB RAM server"-insane.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: please provide more details to help us understand your problem

Comment: I don't really know what else to add. I'm using the Web3 API.

Comment: some code snippet ,etc

Comment: @LoonixTarballs I can't answer your question but I just wanted to comment saying I really like your handle, lol